# Is there a way Blender can export to PDF(.U3D)?

Tags: export

I'd like to export my 3D models in Blender to .U3D file format so that I can place them inside PDFs. I could use this at work when I send reports to clients, in my resume, etc. There is an old plugin that does this, but it doesn't work anymore. Has anyone out there made a plugin/fixed the old one?

Comment: Requests to do work for you are considered off topic. You can try https://blenderartists.org/forum/forumdisplay.php?51-Jobs there are two forums there: one for paid work one for volunteer work.

Comment: True. I changed the wording to reflect what I originally was looking for, to see if anyone had already made one/fixed the old one. I'll head over to the forum you linked next.

Comment: Also, this isn't a duplicate as I'm asking for an export to a specific file format (.u3d) that can be imported into a PDF. The other user seems to be looking for a "export screenshot of GUI to PDF" function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot see it in the the list of Import/Export. However, you can convert to another format, and use an additional tool. These formats can be read/written by Meshlab: **PLY**, *STL*, OFF, **OBJ**, **3DS**, VRML 2.0, U3D, **X3D** and **COLLADA**. Export as one one of the highlighted formats, import it into Meshlab, and export to U3D.

Comment: That's exactly what I was able to do. Thanks for actually reading my question and taking the time to answer it, unlike the users that marked my question as a duplicate.