# 3D PDF from Blender

Tags: export, add-on, file-format

i have a customer that uses 3D views of products and he send me a PDF actually containing a 3D model which you can turnaround and observe. How I get this PDF containing 3D object out of blender or what conventor do I need?

Thanks for answers.

Comment: Hello :). It seems there is already a similar question https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/72572/78972. Just let us know, if it works for you.

Comment: Oh, I somehow missed this post, its about the exact problem, but the solution is little bit obsolete and does not work for me. They advice to use meshlab to convert files to U3D which should be usable for PDF, but the Meshlab itself is now 4years old and has a bug when exporting file to U3D it was supposed to be repaired in the next version which never came out.
Is there another way to make interactive 3D PDF or do I have to use some convertion to U3D because its kind of wierd that you have to have a separate paid program just for convertion. And do all the proces just to have a simple PDF

Comment: Hello :). I'm no developer, but if adding full support for 3D Pdf was that simple, I'm sure there would be an addon for that. Maybe there is. You can also suggest this to [Blender developers](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/) and ask them. Anyway, good luck, and let us know what you found out :).

Comment: Ok, so far I ended with photoshop which I have access to. Photoshop can actually open some 3D files like .OBJ, textures are OK the materials not so, there are some informations missing as for example gold PBR material now looks just like dark yellow and the photoshop export to U3D or directly exports a PDF with the 3D file which is awesomly simple. If the Blender would have some export for PDF or other formats that non-graphic users can see as an amateurs it would be great for customer service.
I will dig more deeper to find out about the materials convertion. And also as the developers.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Consider posting your comment as an answer, because for many people Photoshop is a readily available solution. Until there's native support in Blender, that's our best bet. And thanks for posting on rightclickselect :).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so far I ended with photoshop which I have access to. Photoshop can actually open some 3D files like .OBJ, textures are OK the materials not so, there are some informations missing as for example gold PBR material now looks just like dark yellow and the photoshop export to U3D or directly exports a PDF with the 3D file which is awesomly simple. If the Blender would have some export for PDF or other formats that non-graphic users can see as an amateurs it would be great for customer service. I will dig more deeper to find out about the materials convertion. And also ask the developers